# insert the value automatically in input text when another value is given to another input text

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

In form, I want to insert the value of amount(text input) when value of rate(another text input) . The value which will be inserted in amount is the multiplication of rate and quantity. The value of quantity is taken from database. Here, the value of rate will be inserted by user.
After insertion of amount, the value can not be changed. How can i do this?

I have tried below code but result is showing zero every time:

**View**

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Rate</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate" placeholder="Rate" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity" value="<?php echo $object['sheet'];  ?> " required readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Amount</label>
  <?php
  $sheet = $object['sheet'];
  $rate = $this->input->post('rate');
  $amount = $sheet*$rate;
  echo $amount;
  }
  ?>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount;?>" placeholder="Amount" required>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I correct that you want to change the input amount to the value of rate*quantity whenever the value of rate changes?

Comment: Yes, you are write and value of amount must be shown when the value iof rate is inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input[name="rate"]').on('change',function() {
   var amount = $(this).val()*$('input[name="quantity"]').val();
   $('input[name="amount"]').val(amount);
})
});
```

Don't forget to include the jQuery api.
Also, don't forget to validate the amount after the form is submitted, as users can easily manipulate the value of the input.

Comment: can i write this code inside 'value' attribute of input type?

Comment: No, just put them into <script> tags in the <head>.

Comment: okay. its working. but when i insert the value in rate it shows the value on blank page other than in the text box of amount. So, how can i write the value in value attribute of amount.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery API? And dit you get an error message?

Comment: k, That was my mistake. You solved it. Thank you, so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript for calculation.

I modified your code for your requirement. Your just need to set rate value dynamically from database. Here is your code :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Rate</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rate" placeholder="Enter Rate" id="rate" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="quantity" placeholder="quantity" value="2" id="qnty" required readonly>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Amount</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" value="" id="amt" placeholder="Amount" required>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  $('#rate').keyup(function(){
    var rate = parseInt($('#rate').val());
    var qnty = parseInt($('#qnty').val());
    var amt = parseInt(rate*qnty);
    if(isNaN(amt)){
      $('#amt').val('Enter valid rate');
    } else {
      $('#amt').val(amt);
    }

  });

</script>
```